# MS Access: how to enforce only one owner selected from two different tables

Tags: database, ms-access

I have 3 tables Labelled Product, Individual and Company. 
Now a product is owned by either a company or individual, not by both, and is always owned by one of them. The question I'm asking is how should I go about doing this?

Would I have a fourth table labelled owner that has companyID, ProductID, IndividualID and allow null value for either companyID or IndividualID. But this seems like it would create a lot of null values and I would still have to enforce only one owner. In this case all three of these attributes would be Foreign Keys pointing back to their respective tables. This doesn't seem like a very good way of doing it, but I can't think of a better way yet. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In general SQL questions, it is a good idea to include enough of the table schemas to allow people to understand their structure (you can use `...` to indicate omitted material).  Here you included table names; it is surprising how often people don't.  Good first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enforce the kind of rule that you are looking for using SQL declarative referential integrity.

Consider whether Individuals and Companies are really one "kind" of thing or whether they at least have a set of core attributes (columns) that could be represented in a single table (with linked tables for the special columns that are not the same between the two kinds of entities).  If so, refactor your database so that those common elements are in that table, and use the id from that table as the owner id in the Product table.

If you decide that Individuals and Companies are so different that they can't be combined into a single table you could use your approach of a fourth table, or you could enforce the relationship in code.  You could also choose to switch to a database engine which supports stored procedures and triggers and enforce the relationship in a trigger, but at a cost to performance.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply Larry, I now have question about your reply. If i combine Individuals and company into one table i have several attributes that only a company has which i would put into another table. How would i make sure that this linked table is only used when it is a company. sorry if this sounds like a simple question but am still learning how this all works.

Comment: You would do that through code -- in fact, entering a record into the second table is probably how you would determine a record in the main table is a company, not an individual.